# Counting the occurrences of a character in a string

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xsd

In XSLT 1.0, I have a node with values having special characters, numbers, alphabets. From this , I need to take the count of a particular character. Consider the below node.

```
<sample>abc.123.@#$,def$%^123.kl.lo</sample>
```

In this, I need to get the count of decimal points alone. So, the result should be 4. Please put your thoughts. Below are few codes that I tried.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/sample[contains(., '.')]) "/>

<xsl:value-of select="count(//sample[.])"/>
```

Comment: *Linq*? E.g. `string source = ...; int count = source.Count(c => c == '.');`

Comment: What did you try? anything?

Comment: yes I tried the below ones.
        
<xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/sample[contains(., '.')]) "/>

<xsl:value-of select="count(//sample[.])"/>

Comment: @NareshArvind: edit your question and show what you have tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this code your problem solve

```
string-length(//sample) - string-length(translate(//sample, '.', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped and my problem is solved.